continuouty of operators
I was given a task to understand, wheter operators $A$ and $B$ are compact, $$\displaystyle A:\ell_2 \rightarrow L_1(\mathbb{R}), (Ax)(t) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x(k)}{\cosh^2(kt)},$$ $$B:c_0 \rightarrow L_1(\mathbb{R}), (Bx)(t) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x(k)}{k^4+t^2}.$$
But I cannot even understand, why these operators are continuous. I tried to do the following:
$\displaystyle\lVert Ax\rVert = \left|\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x(k)}{\cosh^2(kt)}dt\right| \le \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\lVert x\rVert_2\sqrt{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\cosh^4(kt)}}dt$. Is $\displaystyle\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\sqrt{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\cosh^4(kt)}}dt < \infty$? How can one understand it?
$\displaystyle\lVert Bx\rVert = \left|\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x(k)}{k^4+t^2}dt\right| \le \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\lVert x\rVert_\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2k^2|t|}dt$. The problem there is that $\displaystyle\frac{1}{|t|}$ is not integrable.
How can be continuity be shown in this case?

Let $(e_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ be a Schauder basis for a Banach space $X$ and let $A:X\to Y$ be a continuous operator. Then $A$ is compact iff $$\lim_N \|A|_{\text{span}\{e_k:k\geqslant N\}}\|=0.$$ I think that will be the best method to use here, and it will more or less come out of the proof of continuity.
Note that for $t>0$, $$4\cosh^2(kt)=[e^{kt}+e^{-kt}]^2\geqslant e^{2kt}.$$  For $t<0$, $$4\cosh^2(kt)=[e^{kt}+e^{-kt}]^2 \geqslant e^{-2kt}.$$  So $$\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{\cosh^2(kt)}dt =O\Bigl(\int_0^\infty e^{-2kt}dt\Bigr)=O(k^{-1}).$$  By the triangle inequality, we have $$\Bigl\|\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x(k)}{\cosh^2(kt)}\Bigr\|_1\leqslant \sum_{k=1}^\infty |x(k)|Ck^{-1}$$ for some constant $C$. Use Cauchy Schwartz to get that this is finite. This also allows us to get estimates on $\|A|_{\text{span}\{e_k:k\geqslant N\}}\|$  in terms of the $\ell_2$ norms of tails of $(k^{-1})_{k=1}^\infty$.
For $a>0$, since $\frac{d}{dt}\arctan(t/a)=\frac{1}{a^2+t^2}$, we can directly calculate $$\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{1}{k^4+t^2}dt = \frac{\pi}{k^2}.$$  Therefore $$\Bigl\|\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x(k)}{k^4+t^2}\Bigr\|_1\leqslant \max_k |x(k)|\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\pi}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^3}{6}\max_k |x(k)|.$$
